# Apache Spark with an embedded Http server

Tags: http, apache-spark

I would like to embed an http server on port 9090 in my Spark application, in order to trigger the application by injecting several parameters and a query.

I managed to start the application in local[*] mode, and interact with my application through the Http Server.

However, when I spark-submit my application through --master spark://hn0-sddlin:7077 --deploy-mode cluster ...
I cannot interact with my http server.

Any return of experience you can share?

Thank you

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I had to open the ports on the VM then I was able to invoke it.